# Media queries for responsive design

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to develope a website with the responsive design and I know that I have to use media queries, I used them and they work fine on my desktop (When I resize the window the look change).
So I was wondering if there are some 'standard values' to use them with smartphones/tablet/desktop.
I've looked at other questions but are too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of searching on CSS a you may found this :

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Basically (if you read the comment lines), for classic CSS (meaning no `less/sass`), you would replace `@screen-sm-min` by 768px for instance. Or whatever fits you.

Answer (score 1):

Basics of RWD you can refer

Google Web Fundamentals http://blog.froont.com/9-basic-principles-of-responsive-web-design/

Froont's basic principles http://blog.froont.com/9-basic-principles-of-responsive-web-design/